# PHP doesn't give a proper output for month substraction

Tags: php, datetime

Code:

`$time = strtotime('2020-03-31');
 echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month', $time));`

Expected Result: Any date from Feb 2020

Actual Result: 2020-03-02

Is there any better way to add or subtract a month from a given date?

Comment: I'm expecting exactly -1 month (since we give '-1 month' for the process)

Comment: Remove the day (31). just let year and month stay ==>. `$time = strtotime('2020-03');`

Answer (score 2):

Months are an awkward interval to work with, because they don't have a fixed length. Should the algorithm assume that by "1 month" you mean "30 days", or "31 days", or should it just try subtracting 1 from the "month" field in the date structure?

The last option is what is happening here: given "2020-03-31", PHP's date library is subtracting 1 from the "03" to give "2020-02-31". Since that's an invalid date (February 2020 had 29 days), it then "normalises" it to a real date - 2 days after the 29th February was the 2nd March.

Probably you want to use a more specific period to subtract, like 30 days - although note that if the initial input is "2020-03-01" that will give you "2020-01-31", not "2020-02-01".

Ultimately, this is a problem with our irregular calendar, rather than with PHP. It's really up to you to define what you mean by "a month before", and use a more specific algorithm that captures that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make code like below

```
<?php
$time = strtotime('2020-03-1 -32 days');
echo date('M-Y', $time); // output Feb-2020
?>
```

The above code will return date as you expected

Comment: Thanks. But my concern is when we specify '-1 month' it shouldn't display the same month. (I'm guessing PHP assumes 30 days for a month).

The given output (for 2020-03-31') is not acceptable.
Is this an expected way that we get from PHP?

Comment: It's not really clear how this answers the question. Although the code is formatted differently, it's actually only giving the expected answer because you've picked the 20th as the start date rather than the 31st.

Comment: $time = strtotime('2020-03-31 -32 days'); this is always return previous month

Comment: @dodiyavijay Sure, but what about `$time = strtotime('2020-03-01 -32 days');`? As I say in my answer, there's no generic solution to this, you have to pick a definition that makes sense for what you're actually trying to do.